# count of Balance installments

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a requirement to write a MS-SQL stored procedure, the requirement is 
**Table 1**
It consists total student fee to be paid in installments
**EX:**

```
SID   SNAME     INST.Date   Amount

123     XYZ     01-01-2013  3500
123     XYZ     01-05-2013  3500
123     XYZ     01-10-2013  3500
123     XYZ     01-04-2014  3500
123     XYZ     01-06-2014  3500
```

`
**Table 2**
It consists Payment recd details

```
SID     SNAME    Paydate    amoount
123     XYZ     01-01-2013  1167
123     XYZ     01-02-2013  1167
123     XYZ     01-03-2013  1167
123     XYZ     01-05-2013  1750
123     XYZ     01-05-2013  1750
123     XYZ     01-10-2013  1167
123     XYZ     01-10-2013  1167
```

now the requirement is as on jan2014,how many installment to paid,what is the Recd amount, no of balance installments to be paid as on jan-14.

**Expected output**

```
SID     Sname   Total Inst.Amt as on01.01.2014  Paid.amount     Balance amt     Balance.Installments

123     XYZ     10500                           9335            1165            1
```

For reference I gave one student data.

The stored procedure should run for 36000 students.

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: Nice homework assignment! Why don't you share with us your attempts so far?

Comment: What does the column `Balance.Installments` represent? In your example it has `1`. How did you arrive at this value for the sample student?

Comment: Thanks for all valuable outputs

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually i am looking out for balance installments, i will try to make better understanding, small ex: Total Installment amount = 100,single installment = 50 ,paid 40, balance 60 ,balance installments = 2.because single installment is 50 but balance is 60,it exceeding one installments so we need to count balance installments as 2,hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that will give you what you want, expect `Balance.Installments` I don't know what it means :

```
SELECT distinct t1.SID
, t1.SNAME
, t1.Total_Inst
, t2.Paid_amount AS 'Paid.Amount'
, t1.Total_Inst - t2.Paid_amount as 'Balance amt'
, CEILING( (t1.Total_Inst - t2.Paid_amount) / t.Amount ) as 'Balance.Installments'
FROM
    table_1 as t
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SID, SNAME, SUM(Amount) as Total_Inst 
      FROM table_1 
      WHERE Date < STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') group by SID, SNAME
    )
    ON ( t1.SID = t.SID AND t1.SNAME = t.SNAME )
    AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT SID, SNAME, SUM(Amount) as Paid_amount 
      FROM table_2 
      WHERE Paydate < STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') group by SID, SNAME
    ) AS t2
    ON ( t1.SID = t2.SID AND t1.SNAME = t2.SNAME )
```

Comment: Your `JOIN` should be a `LEFT JOIN`, so that for students that haven't made any payment, you can still show the installments and balance due (which would be the full amount).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually i am looking out for balance installments, i will try to make better understanding, small ex: Total Installment amount = 100,single installment = 50 ,paid 40, balance 60 ,balance installments = 2.because single installment is 50 but  balance is 60,it exceeding one installments so we need to count balance installments as 2,hope this will help you

Comment: Now if Total Installment amount = 100, single installment = 20 ,paid 10, balance 90 so balance installments = __5__ ? Is it right ?

Comment: Yes Sir,Total installment,paid,balance amount should be as on 01-01-2014.

Comment: thanks you rida,and all guys who gave valuable answers

Answer (score 0):

why you will need to run for 36000  record at one time.Also what is actially installment.There is only one instalment for any student no several.So i think  database is lil wrong.
There should only one instalment amount and time interval(due date) per student in table.

Check the latest change.It is only for one student .

```
   Declare @student table(SID int,SNAME varchar(50),INST Date ,Amount int)
insert into @student
select 123,'XYZ','01-01-2013',3500 union all
select 123,  'XYZ',  '01-05-2013',  3500 union all
select 123,  'XYZ',  '01-10-2013',  3500 union all
select 123,  'XYZ',  '01-04-2014',  3500 union all
select 123,  'XYZ',  '01-06-2014',  3500

Declare @instalmentamount float
select @instalmentamount=amount from @student where sid=123
--select @instalmentamount
Declare @Table2 table(SID int,Paydate date,amoount int)
insert into @Table2
select 123,    '01-01-2013',  1167 union all
select 123,    '01-02-2013',  1167 union all
select 123,    '01-03-2013',  1167 union all
select 123,    '01-05-2013',  1750 union all
select 123,    '01-05-2013',  1750 union all
select 123,    '01-10-2013',  1167 union all
select 123,  '01-10-2013',  1167

declare @input date='01-01-2014'

;With CTE as
(select s.SID, sum(s.amount) as [Total Inst.Amt ] from @student s 
where s.INST<=@input
group by s.SID),
cte1 as
(
select t.SID, sum(t.amoount) as [Paid.amount] from @Table2 t 
where t.Paydate<=@input
group by t.SID
)

select c.sid,
(select top 1 s.SNAME from @student s where s.SID=c.SID) [Name],
c.[Total Inst.Amt ],c1.[Paid.amount], 
c.[Total Inst.Amt ]-c1.[Paid.amount] [BalanceAmount],cast(((c.[Total Inst.Amt ]-c1.[Paid.amount])/@instalmentamount) as int)+1 [Balance.Installments]
from CTE c inner join cte1 c1 on c.SID=c1.SID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually i am looking out for balance installments, i will try to make better understanding, small ex: Total Installment amount = 100,single installment = 50 ,paid 40, balance 60 ,balance installments = 2.because single installment is 50 but  balance is 60,it exceeding one installments so we need to count balance installments as 2,hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS...

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        T.SNAME,
        T.AMT  'Total Inst.Amt as on01.01.2014',
         ISNULL(SUM(amoount),0) AS 'PAID AMT',
        T.AMT - ISNULL(SUM(amoount),0) AS 'BALANCE AMT' ,     
        CEILING((T.AMT-  ISNULL(SUM(amoount),0) )/( T.InstAmt*1.)) 'Balance.Installments'
FROM 
    (
     SELECT ID,SNAME,SUM(AMT)AMT,MAX(AMT) AS InstAmt FROM @Table1 WHERE DT_ < '01-31-2014' GROUP BY  ID,SNAME
    ) T 
     LEFT JOIN @Table2 P ON P.ID = T.id AND P.Paydate < '01-31-2014'
 GROUP BY t.ID,SNAME,t.InstAmt,T.AMT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually i am looking out for balance installments, i will try to make better understanding, small ex: Total Installment amount = 100,single installment = 50 ,paid 40, balance 60 ,balance installments = 2.because single installment is 50 but  balance is 60,it exceeding one installments so we need to count balance installments as 2,hope this will help you